# DNS Forwarders Not Syncing

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I have two Windows Server DCs, SERVER3 and SERVER4. SERVER3 is the PDCe.

On SERVER3 I changed the DNS forwarders from my ISP to OpenDNS, expecting the change to automatically sync to SERVER4.

It's been over forty-eight hours now, with no sign of success.

How concerned should I be? Does this mean that my DCs aren't syncing correctly, or simply that forwarders aren't considered in a sync operation?

FYI I'm manually checking the sync status every so often using ADRST. (I'd love to automate that somehow, with emailed status reports, but such knowledge escapes me.)

Comment: AFAIK, the DNS server configuration settings (forwarders, root hint servers, etc.) aren't synced as part of AD/SYVOL replication.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the DNS server configuration settings (forwarders, root hint servers, etc.) aren't synced as part of AD/SYVOL replication.

Comment: Yep. The domains (can) sync, the configuration of a server does not. Sort of makes sense when you think of complex domain setups in many countries.